# Why declaring an anonymous JavaScript function as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, web, ember.js

I don't understand why some JavaScript frameworks like ember.js use an anonymous function as a function parameter value. I would understand if the function was returning something, but it is not.

Here is a sample code of the routing system of ember.js that demonstrate my question:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
  this.route("favorites", { path: "/favs" });
});
```

Please explain me why this code creates an anonymous function as a parameter.

Comment: this is function pointer like other language.you are passing a function pointer and callback whenever it completes task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because that function `.map` is an async function, and that anonymous function is what to run *AFTER* `.map` completes.

Typically async functions look like:

```
function async(callback) {
    //async stuff, yada
    callback();
}
```

That `callback` is what you pass in to run once the async operations complete

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't realize that the method was asynchronous. It makes more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

So basically this creates a way to encapsulate functionality, and run the route set up w/e they need to. I'm not 100% familiar with amber, but my guess is that they do some setup and checking/validation before initializing the routes. Because you pass in the anonymous function, they can now defer the set up you specify until everything is set and ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

A function passed in as a parameter means that the function will be run at some point during (or at the end of) the outer function. Often this is used to pass in a callback function.

For example, the map method might do some stuff and then call the anonymous function when finished:

```
function map(function) {
    // Do some stuff
    function();
}
```